# Using pushState to create "links" on an AJAX website produces 404s

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have my website set up with a single html file that uses on-click javascript functions to display various sections of the site differently as the user navigates around. The main page contains an audio player that I want to keep playing as the user navigates, which is why I've chosen the AJAX route.

I've implemented pushState across the site to produce URLs for each section that the user navigates to. These links don't work.

I have a couple questions regarding this: should I be using pushState to generate these URLs, or am I going about producing links the wrong way?  And is there a way I can have a user reload a deeply-embedded page in the site, and then have the page constructed from the javascript somehow server-side?

EDIT: I feel like maybe if I could have all these links routed to a javascript file that then built the appropriate page, maybe that would work? Not sure if that's the way to go about it.

```js
 $('#menu a').click(function() {
   var page = $(this).attr('href');
   history.pushState({}, '', page);
   $('#news').load('content/' + page + '.php');
   return false;
 });
```

Here's an example of how the menu is running this jQuery function on click, and then using pushState to make a new URL. Then, it loads in content into the #news div from the appropriate php file.

Is there any way I can link to this "state" of the page? I've been reading Jose Maria Arranz Santamaria's ["Single Page Interface Manifesto"](http://itsnat.sourceforge.net/php/spim/spi_manifesto_en.php), which has a lot of great info, but I'm sort of wondering what I should do next.

Comment: no code? come on!

Comment: I edited and added a jQuery function that is loading an alternate state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Pushstate is not the way you should use if the links don't actually work.
You can use the hashes to implement this easily.
You the event `onhashchange`.

The hashes are stored in the window.location.hash property. There would be no need to modify the browser history as well.

Refer to [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange) and [Hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Looking into onhashchange now.

Comment: If I've bookmarked example.com/#foobar, and I go to open this link, how does the browser know what to do with that hash?

Comment: Or, how can I get my javascript to catch this hash from the bookmarked link and do something with it?

Comment: Actually, I think I found an answer. I included an "if(window.location.hash)" function in my $(document).ready(function(). This checks to see if the URL that was clicked has a hash, and then performs an action to correctly render the page. Thanks again for your help.